# How to write a custom powershell host

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, nuget

Similar to nuget

Looking for any starter material hopefully before delving into the debugger

Comment: Hi All, I have a related questions Which method (in PSHostUserInterface) is called when Write-Error is called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563(v=VS.85).aspx) has a [section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563(v=VS.85).aspx) devoted to writing a PowerShell host in the [PowerShell SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714469(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation, which is a nice starting point.

Besides that a [search](http://www.google.nl/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=writing+a+powershell+host) returns the following:

1. http://powershellstation.com/2009/10/12/writing-your-own-powershell-hosting-app-part-1-introduction/
2. http://dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/02/how-to-host-powershell-in-a-wpf-application/

Answer (score 10):

There is no *great* documentation.  I've learned most of what I know by experimentation and example.  And reflection.  Not the personal kind, the reverse engineering kind.

Joel Bennett's [PoshConsole](http://poshconsole.codeplex.com/) is probably the best OSS example of a custom host that I've found.  The [StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com) codebase also contains a simple interactive host based on winforms.

Hosting can be relatively simple depending on the level of interactivity you're looking for.  If you just want to run some script files, the code is as simple as this:

```
using( var runspace = RunspaceFactory.Create() )
{
  runspace.Open();
  using( var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline( "./myscript.ps1" ) )
  {
    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    // ... process the results of running myscript.ps1
  }
}
```

If you need any kind of interactivity, such as prompting the user from script, you're pretty much limited drinking the koolaid and implementing most of the PSHost, PSHostUserInterface, and PSHostRawUserInterface contracts.  Again, I would look at the existing living examples before diving down the rabbit hole on your own.

Comment: You're not creating any PowerShell hosts here. -- Just a Runspace. -- i.e. you are not implementing `PSHost` anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

I have a series of blog posts dedicated to this.

[Here](http://powershellstation.com/2009/10/12/writing-your-own-powershell-hosting-app-part-1-introduction/)'s the first.

I have also implemented a debugger.  I'd be glad to answer questions you might have.  Contact info on my blog.

Also, [here](http://code.google.com/p/farnet/wiki/PowerShellFar)'s a project that actually implemented a debugger using the API...it's the only place I've found any published code to do that.

Comment: Just realized that the first link in the other answer is the same as I gave.  I read up to MSDN and stopped.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find here under the blog from which I built my own PowerShell which interpret scripts without showing any windows.

[Blog from Leporelo](http://www.leporelo.eu/blog.aspx?id=run-scheduled-tasks-with-winform-gui-in-powershell)

It's really the few first lines you need and the shortcut to PowerShell SDK.

[the shell responding my own need](http://www.silogix.fr/Blog-Silogix/powershell-ne-sait-pas-demarrer-sans-afficher-une-fenetre.aspx) (sorry in french)