# executing powershell scripts from windows c++ application

Tags: c++, powershell, winapi

Currently my C++ application launching/executing powershell scripts using createprocess method(can be achieved using system or shellexecute). This takes a while because it launches a commandline and then executing the script. Is there any windows API available to call powershell scripts from C++?

Comment: [Windows PowerShell Host Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart) is listed under the *Legacy PowerShell SDK* documentation section. Sounds like that allows you to execute scripts in your own hosting environment. I don't know whether that is still supported, or whether it provides interfaces for consuming it from a native application.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve it through pure C++ and windows API, you can refer to [Would like to run PowerShell code from inside a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499270/would-like-to-run-powershell-code-from-inside-a-c-program) and [C++ and Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634220/c-and-powershell)

Answer (score -1):

The PowerShell executables (powershell.exe, powershell_ise.exe, pwsh.exe) are just hosts themselves... and yes you can create your own.

['create your own PowerShell host'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27create%20your%20own%20powershell%20host%27&t=h_&ia=web)

> PowerShell Runspaces When you execute PowerShell commands it is
> actually the runspace that is doing the execution work and handling
> the execution pipeline. The host is mostly responsible for handling
> input and output streams to interact with the runspace. Examples of
> hosts are PowerShell.exe, PowerShell ISE or a custom console, WPF,
> WinForms or Windows service application. The different hosts interact
> with the PowerShell runspace behind the scenes. When you create your
> own host you are creating a runspace instance and passing it commands
> to execute.
>
> Creating A Runspace Creating the default runspace is pretty easy, just
> call:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
```

> Note: You will need a reference to System.Management.Automation for
> the code to work.
>
> Video: [Hosting PowerShell In WPF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=5&v=X6ClzyoxVOw&feature=emb_logo)

So, this really a duplicate of this SO Q&A

> [How to write a custom powershell host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021662/how-to-write-a-custom-powershell-host)

Comment: The question is explicitly asking for doing this with C++. You have posted C# code (presumably) and provided instructions for doing this from a .NET application.